# stucked with errors when I try to build my old IOS app

Tags: objective-c

We have an app which is published since 2016 and we need to update the code so when I opened the source code I got plenty of errors which I don't understand because we didn't change anything in source code.
following two example of the errors

_application = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; it shows an error of use of undeclared identifier but I already declare it above in source code
also we were using the uiwebview whihc is deprecated now how can we migrate to ‎WKWebView ?[I attached an image showing an example of one of errors I am getting when building the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxMJS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is saying "@end must appear in an Objective-C context".  This suggests that there is a problem higher up in the source file.  Have you imported "VideoDetailViewController.h", or is there possibly something wrong in THAT file?

Comment: Yes I imported the file and all needed files but still getting this error.